# replacing a substring in a string containing quotes

Tags: java, string

My input string is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><tag1><tag2></tag2></tag1>
```

I want to replace below part:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><tag1>
```

with spaces.

So I wrote:

```
String final = inputString.replaceFirst("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?><tag1>", "");
```

However, its not working.

On printing final to the console, it is still same as inputString.

What is the issue ?

Comment: replaceFirst takes a regex, and <? have special meanings.

Comment: @assylias: was not knowing that replaceFirst takes a regex. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to use a regex replacement. Just use the plain simple `replace` method and the code will work. The string literal you are using will be correct in that case.

Answer (score 2):

The search part is a regular expression, so you will need to escape characters that are interpreted as special characters by regular expressions (e.g. `?`).

Annoyingly, you also have to escape the escape character so that it is not interpreted as an escape sequence for a special character (like `\n`) in the String. That means you need to put `\\?` where you have `?`:

```
String output = inputString.replaceFirst("<\\?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"\\?><tag1>", "");
```

Alternatively, since the string is not likely to occur more than once, you can use the `replace()` method of `String`. This method does not use regular expressions, so you don't need to escape anything:

```
String output = inputString.replace("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?><tag1>", "");
```